# MVC best practice

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC (I'm using codeigniter) and was wondering where I should put a "cut_description" function.

My model retrieves a list of events including their description. If the description is too long, I would need to cut it after the first *n* words, and add a "read more" link, so the view doesn't get too cluttered.

What would be the best practice?

1. add the logic to cut after n
   words to the model?
2. add the logic to the controller?
3. add it to the view?

I think 3 would be the easier (I have to loop through results anyway), but I'm not sure this would comply with MVC.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are modifying information to properly *display* it, it should go into the view.

I doubt it should be in the model primarily because if the data was always going  to be shortened, you would probably would store it shortened.

Comment: Yes, put it in the view. I would only suggest moving it into the model (which might be view specific, and thus require controller manipulation) if you were going to do this in a lot of different places **and** either there was potential for unsafe conditions (e.g. security) or it was overly complex or confusing. But this seems like a clear case of a simple display issue so yes, do it in the view.