# MVC quandaries, should this go in view or controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I was wondering what the best practice would be for where to place a certain piece of code, either controller or view (or even model if I'm way off).

Currently, the application retrieves information from the database, one column is "type". Then based on the type, there is a switch statement that prepares the html tags to be displayed in the view.

Something like:

```
    foreach ($data as &$dataPoint)
    {
        foreach ($dataPoint as &$postItem)
        {
            switch ($postItem['type'])
            {
                case "image":
                    $postItem['content'] = "<img src=\.$postItem['content']."\" />";
                    break;
                case "youtube":
                    $postItem['content'] = "<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$postItem['content']."?showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm just lost as to where this should go, should it be directly in the controller, before it's passed on to the view? Or should it be placed on the top of a view file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep in your view, like others have mentioned.

You can indeed create a view format helper file to take care of some non-generic php functions

```
foreach ($data as &$dataPoint)
    {
        foreach ($dataPoint as &$postItem)
        {
            //format_helper.php
            get_content_type($postItem);
        }
    }
```

**format_helper.php**

```
if(!function_exists('get_content_type'){
    function get_content_type(array $postItem){
         switch ($postItem['type'])
            {
                case "image":
                    echo "<img src=\.$postItem['content']."\" />";
                    break;
                case "youtube":
                    echo "<iframe src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/".$postItem['content']."?showinfo=0\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>";
                    break;
            }
    }
})
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is the first code snipped to be in view or the controller?

Comment: In the view yes, $data is provided via the controller

Answer (score 3):

If it's display logic, it should go in the view. As that seems to be display logic, the view seems like the best place.

This answer explains a little differently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574953/1324019

Comment: So if that's the case - does that mean that the view page would be something like:

<?php
function format() {...}

?>
<html>...</html>

Comment: @bswinnerton Something like that. This page has some nice examples of how to use views in codeigniter: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen that page, but none of the examples include logic inside the view, that's why I ask.

Comment: @bswinnerton The last example includes a foreach loop - basically the same thing as what you're doing. If this function is only going to be necessary for this particular view, yes, I'd declare it at the top of the view and then just call it inside php tags as the link demonstrates.

Comment: Last question, I swear :). If it's not just going to be in that one view, where would you put it?

Comment: I haven't used codeigniter enough to answer definitively, but in asp.net mvc I'd create a custom html helper, looks like you might be able to do something similar in CI: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/html_helper.html